# configurations to communicate local freeswitch with freeswitch on cloud

Tags: freeswitch

I want to make my local freeswitch communicate with the cloud freeswitch server. I am running recording application on local freeswitch and playing application on cloud. 
Both of them are getting invoked by origination command but my recording app is not able to record wav files played by cloud application.

I used following command On fs_cli: 
**originate loopback/126/default &bridge(sofia/internal/1235@192.168.0.130)**

```
<include>
 <extension name="Dial to dialplan in cloud">
  <condition field="destination_number" expression="^126$">
   <action application="answer"/>
   <action application="bridge" data="sofia/internal/121@54.225.247.53"/>
  </condition>
 </extension>
</include>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the SIP traffic with wireshark?

It seems that you're connecting to port 5060 on 54.225.247.53. But 5060 is only used for authenticated INVITE's.

Unauthenticated INVITE's are accepted by port 5080.

So, you need to decide first if you want authenticated calls, then who makes the authentication, then configure the Sofia gateways accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions I will try it and revert soon

Comment: I have changed the port to 5080 in both the system in following file     /usr/local/src/freeswitch/src/mod/endpoints/mod_sofia/conf/sofia.conf.xml

Comment: I have changed the port to 5080 in both the system in following file     /usr/local/src/freeswitch/src/mod/endpoints/mod_sofia/conf/sofia.conf.xml and restarted both servers. but the same issue is occurring, can u please help me

Comment: skype: "ssinyagin", but I can only offer help if there's a budget :)